# Android transitions preview

Tags: java, android, transition

I'm trying to add some transitions to my app. Is there any place where I can see a preview of the default transitions

ImageSwitcher

AdapterViewFlipper

StackView

TextSwitcher

ViewAnimator

ViewFlipper

ViewSwitcher

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, but it's easy enough to create your own test project to test.